# 'Template' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, django

Whenever I run the code, the error is this:

> 'Template' object has no attribute 'replace'

Any help would be nice. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your **value**  for what you are replacing.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
template = get_template("user/ticket_print.html")
```

returns a `Template` object and not a `string` containing the code you put in your template (which I think you expect). And the `Template` object does not have a method called `replace()` resulting in your error.

To access the string you can use

```
template.template.source
```

So I think in your case a slight change in your view could do the trick:

```
def ticket_print(request, cartitem_id):
    item = get_object_or_404(CartItem, object_id=cartitem_id)
    template = get_template("user/ticket_print.html")
    value = template.template.source
    html_result = render_template(value, {"itest": item.cart,},)

   return html_to_pdf(html_result, name=f"Ticket_Print{item}")
```

Comment: I got it. and I tried it's work. Thank you very much.